# Best practice for form w/ radio buttons and checkbox with same name

Tags: html, forms, checkbox, radio-button

I have a form that has a list of radio buttons and one checkbox that represents a special "button". All form elements have the same name:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="channel" id="prv" value="ch1">
<input type="radio" name="channel" value="ch2">
<input type="radio" name="channel" value="ch3">
<input type="radio" name="channel" value="ch4">
```

My idea is that once the checkbox is checked, all the other radio buttons are disabled (which works quite well with jQuery). If the checkbox is unchecked, the user can select some channel with the radio buttons.

But when I submit the form, it doesn't work at all.

```
$('#prv').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(".fc_exp input").attr('disabled',true); <--RADIO BUTTONS
            $(".fc_exp input").removeAttr('checked'); <--RADIO BUTTONS
        } else {
            $(".fc_exp input").attr('disabled',false); <--RADIO BUTTONS
            $('.fc_exp #ch1, .fc_exp label[for="#ch1"]').prop('checked',true); <--DEFAULT RADIO BUTTON: CHECKED
        }
    })
```

Now my question is: Is there any best practice for this?

Thanks a lot and merry xmas!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using four radio buttons - first one with option "No channel" or whatever option you need here - instead of the checkbox. 
If you really need checkbox and radios - checkbox should be named differently in the form - but this will require additional code on server side to handle it properly.

Comment: The problem is that the other radio buttons are invisible in the first place. Only the checkbox is always visible. This is why I decided to make it like mentioned above - in order to create a good UX

Comment: Basically user is choosing from four options and is always allowed to choose only one of them, am I right? If so, then why are you treating first option in a special way?

Comment: If first checkbox is about something else - maybe it should be named differently? I don't think html allows mixing checkboxes and radios for the same field.

Comment: hm, maybe you you are right. I might change the form structure then. Thanks a lot!